# child selecting throughout document

Tags: css, layout, selector, parent

I am making a presentation website, with slides. Each slide is a div.
I've made classes like: 'layout-50', 'layout-70', to serve as templates for the slides. It looks something like this:

```
<!----------- SLIDE 1 ----------->
<!------------------------------->
<div data-scroll-index="0" class="slide">
    <div class="layout-100"></div>
</div>

<!----------- SLIDE 2 ----------->
<!------------------------------->
<div data-scroll-index="1" class="slide">
    <div class="layout-70">

    </div>
</div>



<!----------- SLIDE 3 ----------->
<!------------------------------->
<div data-scroll-index="2" class="slide">
        <div class="layout-100">
        </div>
</div>
```

In the CSS, I'm calling to these classes with child selectors. The problem is, I can't use nth:child(2) to select the second 'layout-100' for example. Is there anyway I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if it is not dynamic, you can check the index of the parent

```
.slide:nth-child(3) .layout-100 {
}
```

**The problem in your code is there is only one child element inside the slide class div**

> But using nth-child will have a problem in lower than ie9 browsers

Comment: What do you mean by "if it is not dynamic"?

Comment: when you add your slides manually and not coming from any scripts or CMS